# ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Guardian.Plug.authenticated?/1 is undefined or private

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, guardian

I am very new to `Elixir` and `Phoenix`, I am trying to authenticate my application using `{:comeonin, "~> 4.0"}` and `{:guardian, "~> 1.0"}` and have a helper function that checks if the user is logged in:

```ex
defmodule Chatter.ViewHelper do
  def current_user(conn), do: Guardian.Plug.current_resource(conn)
  def logged_in?(conn) do
    Guardian.Plug.authenticated?(conn)
  end
end
```

But I get this error:

```ex
** (UndefinedFunctionError) function Guardian.Plug.authenticated?/1 is undefined or private.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guardian documentation doesn't properly reference some API calls since the upgrade to `v1.0`. You need to call these functions from your custom `MyApp.Guardian` implementation and not from the actual `Guardian` module(s).

Assuming you [followed the guide](https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian/#installation) to implement `MyApp.Guardian`, you need to call:

```ex
MyApp.Guardian.Plug.authenticated?(conn)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Found the solution :)

Answer (score 1):

The error shows that you are trying to call the function without arguments:

```
(UndefinedFunctionError) function Guardian.Plug.authenticated?/0
```

`/0` here means no arguments.

Comment: I am calling like this 
  def logged_in?(conn) do
    Guardian.Plug.authenticated?(conn)
  end

Comment: Updated the Question